# Setting up my own library to be included as a dependency by anyone

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to setup my own library so that others can include it in their `build.gradle` file under dependencies.

So something like `Picasso` has `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` or any other library that you can setup as a dependency in your project

I have no idea where to start looking, or what exactly to look for. Does anyone know and can give me a minimal step-by-step "tutorial" or things that I need to do to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upload your library to a repository like maven central.

There are a few good tutorials out there:

[First](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-guide-to-publish-aar-to-maven-gradle.html)

[Second](http://www.vandalsoftware.com/post/52468430435/publishing-an-android-library-aar-to-a-maven)

[Third](http://zserge.com/blog/gradle-maven-publish.html)